# Doctrine / MySQL, imprecise double?

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, floating-point, gps

I want to save GPS coordinates. Its DOUBLE format. The saving is ok,

```
47.60065481725239
18.03011322140128
```

values appears, but when I try to read them, I get

```
47.600654817252
18.030113221401
```

slightly imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing an example, a good one, of the inherent imprecision of floating point numbers.   You might find it helpful to look up the concept of [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

The commercial GPS system itself doesn't have nearly the precision you can represent with `DOUBLE`.  For most applications `FLOAT` is plenty. But, if you know the terms *Datum* or *Universal Transverse Mercator* and they are important to your application, you may want to use `DOUBLE`.

Still, the positional inaccuracy in GPS due to `DOUBLE` epsilon error is on the order of tenths of Ångstrom units (hundredths of nanometers). You can't even get atoms to hold still long enough to measure their locations so precisely. So don't worry about it.

Please learn how floating point numbers work.

Comment: I do worry, because its not 100% accurrate on google map anymore

Answer (score 1):

By necessity, floating point numbers have limited precision: a `double` is only guaranteed to store [15 significant digits](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/). However that should be more than enough in your case: the earth's radius is 40,075 km, so a `double` should be able to store your position to at least 40 nanometres, which is [approximately the size of a virus particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_nanometres) (presumably your inputs are not this accurate).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it would be worth you exploring the `decimal` data type in MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html

If you set your columns data type as `decimal(16,14)` that would give you 2 digits before the . and 14 after.

Mind you, I wonder what that precision of a GPS coordinate even means...

Comment: I think this is a fairly good example of where you *don't* need a decimal type.